# Derive formula for the area of triangle provided that you know 2 angles and side between them.

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry, proof-writing

I am trying to derive the formula for finding the area of the triangle that uses 2 angles and and 1 side between them.

Formula provided by the book:

> If we know two angles (call them $A$ and $B$) and the side between
>   them call it $b$, then Area = $\frac{b^2 \sin B \sin C}{2 \sin A}$

However, I keep getting different result.

My attempt as follows:

First we draw following picture:
[image]

$\angle YPX = 90^{\circ}$ and $\angle YPZ = 90^{\circ}$

We know that  $\angle YXZ = A$ and $\angle YZX = C$ and XZ = $b$

Let $XP = d$ and $PZ = b-d$

$\tan A = \frac{YP}{XP} = \frac{YP}{d} \implies YP = \tan A \cdot d$

$\tan C = \frac{YP}{PZ} = \frac{YP}{b-d} \implies YP = \tan C \cdot (b-d)$

It follows that $$\tan A \cdot d = \tan C \cdot (b-d)$$
$$d = \frac{\tan C \cdot (b-d)}{\tan A}$$
$$\frac{d}{b-d} = \frac{\tan C}{\tan A}$$
$$\frac{b-d}{d} = \frac{\tan A}{\tan C}$$
$$\frac{b}{d} - 1 = \frac{\tan A}{\tan C}$$
$$\frac{b}{d} = \frac{\tan A}{\tan C} + 1$$
$$\frac{1}{d} = \frac{\tan A}{\tan C \cdot b} + \frac{1}{b}$$
$$\frac{1}{d} = \frac{\tan A}{\tan C \cdot b} + \frac{\tan C}{\tan C \cdot b}$$
$$\frac{1}{d} = \frac{\tan A + \tan C}{\tan C \cdot b} $$
$$ d= \frac{\tan C \cdot b}{\tan A + \tan C} $$
$$ d= \frac{\frac{\sin C}{\cos C} \cdot b}{\frac{\sin A}{\cos A} + \frac{\sin C}{\cos C}} $$
$$ d= \frac{\frac{\sin C}{\cos C} \cdot b}{\frac{\sin A \cos C + \sin C \cos A}{\cos C \cos A} }$$

$$ d = \frac{\frac{\sin C}{\cos C} \cdot b \cdot \cos C \cos A}{\sin A \cos C + \sin C \cos A}$$
$$ d = \frac{\sin C \cos A\cdot b}{\sin A \cos C + \sin C \cos A}$$

We know that $$YP = \tan A \cdot d$$
$$YP = \frac{\sin A}{\cos A} \frac{\sin C \cos A\cdot b}{\sin A \cos C + \sin C \cos A}$$
$$YP = \frac{\sin A}{\cos A} \frac{\sin C \cos A\cdot b}{\sin(A+C)}$$
$$YP =  \frac{\sin A \sin C \cdot b}{\sin(A+C)}$$

Because
$$\text{Area} =\frac{1}{2} \cdot YP \cdot b$$

Then
$$\text{Area} =\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\sin A \sin C \cdot b}{\sin(A+C)} \cdot b$$
$$\text{Area} = \frac{\sin A \sin C \cdot b^2}{2 \sin(A+C)} $$

Which, as can be seen, is different from the one provided by the textbook. I've tried to find areas of several triangles using formula above and [this](https://www.triangle-calculator.com/?what=asa&a1=12&c=3&b1=32&submit=Solve) calculator, both give the same results. However, I'm still unsure whether it is correct. Thus I would like to ask you, is the the derivation (and the formula) above correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is simply use are of triangle is ∆=(1/2)cbSinA=(1/2)abSinB
Therefore ∆^2 = (1/4) acb^2 SinA.SinB
Also ∆=(1/2)acSinC
Dividing both we get Area ∆ =( c^2 SinA.SinB)/2 Sin C